# nonnef locus and discrete valuation.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When $X$ is a smooth projective variety and $D$ is a divisor on $X$, it is known that the nonnef locus
$\mathbf{B}_-(D)$ is the union of the centers of the discrete valuations $\sigma$ such that
$\overline\sigma(D):=\inf${$\sigma(E)|0\leq E\equiv D$}$>0$. But can we say that $\overline\sigma(D)>0$ if and only if Center$(\sigma)$ is contained in the nonnef locus of $D$?
(In other words, can there be a discrete valuation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(D)=0$ and the center of $\sigma$ is still in the nonnef locus of $D$?)

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a smooth projective variety, then $\overline{\sigma}(D)>0$ if and only if $\mathrm{Center}(\sigma)\subseteq \mathbf{B}_-(D)$.
A reference is "Asymptotic invariants of base loci" by Ein, Lazarsfeld, Mustata, Nakamaye, Popa, theorem 2.8

http://de.arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0308/0308116v2.pdf

Actually they do this for a big divisor, but this should imply the same result for all pseudoeffective divisors, by using that $\mathbf{B}_-(D)$ is the union of the non-nef loci of $D+A_m$, where $A_m$ is a sequence of amples that goes to 0.

See also  "Asymptotic base loci on singular varieties" by Cacciola and Di Biagio 
http://de.arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1105/1105.1253v2.pdf

for a generalization to the singular case.